# jQuery show hide parent item on click by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble to toggle (show/hide) div based on button clicked to the list item.

When I tried, it affects to all divs at once. Here is my code. I want toggole per item bases.

```
<div class="list-item">
    <div class="list-content">
        <div class="list-updates">
            <a href="#" class="list-avatar"><img
                        src="images/avatar/avatar_<?php echo ( $i <= 8 ? '0' : NULL ) . $avatars[ $i ] ?>.jpg"
                        alt="user-avatar" width="40"
                        height="40"></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="material-icons"><?php echo get_icon( $update[ $i ] ) ?></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-title"><a href="#"><?php echo $questions[ $i ] ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="ans-box">
            <div class="ans-count"><?php echo $ans[ $i ] ?></div>
            <span><i class="material-icons meta-info-btn">keyboard_arrow_down</i></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="metas">
        <div class="update-info"><a href="#">commented</a> 1 hour ago in <a href="#">Plugins</a> by
            <a href="#">gurjyot</a>
        </div>
        <div class="counters">
            <span class="votes"><i class="material-icons">arrow_upward</i> +1245</span>
            <span class="views"><i class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i> 50.2k</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- list-item -->

$('.list-content .meta-info-btn').click(function () {
    alert('Clicked and found!');
    $(this).closest('.metas').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Try `$(this).closest('.list-item').find('.metas').slideToggle();`.

Comment: @Tushar it's not working. I have already tried it before posting. Any alternative?

Comment: Please add complete, relevant HTML code. It'd be better if you create live demo using StackSnippets.

Comment: Try this $(this).parent().parent().parent().next('.metas').toggle();

Comment: @Tushar This is the code. What else cod you need?

Comment: @CodeLover Is there only one `.metas` element in your code? If this is complete code, there should not be issue of _it affects to all divs at once_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Floating to the closest top parent div and then use find.

```
$(this).closest('.list-item').find(".metas").toggle();
```

```js
// add some data...

var x = "";

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  x += "<div class='list-item'>\
 <div class='list-content'>\
  <div class='list-updates'><a href='#'>img</a></div>\
  <div class='item-title'><a href='#'>Question goes here....?</a></div>\
  <div class='ans-box'>\
    <div class='ans-count'>Answer goes here....</div>\
    <span><i class='material-icons meta-info-btn'>hide meta </i></span>\
  </div>\
 </div>\
  <div class='metas'> META INFO HERE </div>\
</div>\
";
}

$("#contents").append(x);
// ----------------------------------

$('.list-content .meta-info-btn').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.list-item').find(".metas").toggle();
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 5px;
}
.meta-info-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.meta-info-btn {
  background: #CCC;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.list-item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="contents"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$('.list-content .meta-info-btn').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('class');
    alert(id);
    $('#'+id).slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-item">
    <div class="list-content">
        <div class="list-updates">
            <a href="#" class="list-avatar"><img
                        src="images/avatar/avatar_<?php echo ( $i <= 8 ? '0' : NULL ) . $avatars[ $i ] ?>.jpg"
                        alt="user-avatar" width="40"
                        height="40"></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="material-icons"><?php echo get_icon( $update[ $i ] ) ?></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-title"><a href="#"><?php echo $questions[ $i ] ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="ans-box">
            <div class="ans-count"><?php echo $ans[ $i ] ?></div>
            <span class="item-1"><i class="material-icons meta-info-btn">keyboard_arrow_down</i></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="metas" id="item-1">
        <div class="update-info"><a href="#">commented</a> 1 hour ago in <a href="#">Plugins</a> by
            <a href="#">gurjyot</a>
        </div>
        <div class="counters">
            <span class="votes"><i class="material-icons">arrow_upward</i> +1245</span>
            <span class="views"><i class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i> 50.2k</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- list-item -->
```

Comment: Why not use `closest` instead of `parent.parent.parent...`

Comment: great, its working fine.. thanks a lot... is there any better solution than multiple `parent()`?

Comment: @PrasannaVenkatesh `closest` is not working. I have tried that before posting. However, I am sure there must be efficient way to do this.

Comment: If you have only one div with classname "metas", then try using find() instead of parent(). Or you can give an ID for the div and use it to perform functionality.

Comment: Yes you can do something like @vinay told.

Comment: @VinayGayakwad I have a list (loop) having the same structure. So I won't be able to use `find()` probably. I may try using `ID` instead.

Comment: Try this updated ans. You can use a counter php variable in your case $i in place of item-1

Comment: @CodeLover did you try this?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$('.list-content .meta-info-btn').click(function () {
    $(this).parents('.list-content').next('.metas').slideToggle(); 
});
```

```js
$('.list-content .meta-info-btn').click(function () {
    
    $(this).parents('.list-content').next('.metas').slideToggle(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-item">
    <div class="list-content">
        <div class="list-updates">
            <a href="#" class="list-avatar"><img
                        src="images/avatar/avatar_<?php echo ( $i <= 8 ? '0' : NULL ) . $avatars[ $i ] ?>.jpg"
                        alt="user-avatar" width="40"
                        height="40"></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="material-icons"><?php echo get_icon( $update[ $i ] ) ?></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-title"><a href="#"><?php echo $questions[ $i ] ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="ans-box">
            <div class="ans-count"><?php echo $ans[ $i ] ?></div>
            <span><i class="material-icons meta-info-btn">keyboard_arrow_down</i></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="metas">
        <div class="update-info"><a href="#">commented</a> 1 hour ago in <a href="#">Plugins</a> by
            <a href="#">gurjyot</a>
        </div>
        <div class="counters">
            <span class="votes"><i class="material-icons">arrow_upward</i> +1245</span>
            <span class="views"><i class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i> 50.2k</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-content">
        <div class="list-updates">
            <a href="#" class="list-avatar"><img
                        src="images/avatar/avatar_<?php echo ( $i <= 8 ? '0' : NULL ) . $avatars[ $i ] ?>.jpg"
                        alt="user-avatar" width="40"
                        height="40"></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="material-icons"><?php echo get_icon( $update[ $i ] ) ?></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-title"><a href="#"><?php echo $questions[ $i ] ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="ans-box">
            <div class="ans-count"><?php echo $ans[ $i ] ?></div>
            <span><i class="material-icons meta-info-btn">keyboard_arrow_down 1</i></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="metas">
        <div class="update-info"><a href="#">commented</a> 1 hour ago in <a href="#">Plugins</a> by
            <a href="#">gurjyot</a>
        </div>
        <div class="counters">
            <span class="votes"><i class="material-icons">arrow_upward</i> +1245</span>
            <span class="views"><i class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i> 50.2k</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- list-item -->
```

Comment: You can replace `parents` with `closest` and it'll work. `parents` will go up the DOM tree to find if there are any more parents/ancestors having that class. `closest` will get the first ancestor and return. `closest` is better in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you do seperate click events for .meta-info-btn and .list-content as below

```
    $('.meta-info-btn').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.list-content').closest('.metas').slideToggle();
    });

    $('.list-content').click(function () {

        $(this).closest('.metas').slideToggle();
    });
```